# Cant make async work with http in nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous

I have come across a very weird problem using async and http in nodejs. Here is my code :

```
http = require('http');
bl = require('bl');
async = require('async');

var tasks = [];

var dataItems = [];

var callHttp = function(index, callback) {
  http.get(process.argv[index], function(response) {

      response.pipe(bl(function(err, data) {
        if (err)
          return console.log(err);
        dataItems[index] = data.toString();
      }));

      response.on('end', callback);

    })
    .on('error', console.error);
}

var indices = [2, 3, 4, 5];
indices.forEach(function(item) {
  tasks.push(function(callback) {
    callHttp(item, callback);
  });
});



async.parallel(tasks, function(Err) {
  console.log(dataItems);
});
```

Running the above code using

```
node async-http.js 'http://www.google.com/' 'http://academics.vit.ac.in/' 'http://www.example.com'
```

gives me the following error:

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

However, running the same code in a different form (by manually defining the array 'tasks') 
seems to work fine ... :

```
http = require('http');
bl = require('bl');
async = require('async');

var tasks = [];

var dataItems = [];

var callHttp = function(index, callback) {
  http.get(process.argv[index], function(response) {

      response.pipe(bl(function(err, data) {
        if (err)
          return console.log(err);
        dataItems[index] = data.toString();
      }));

      response.on('end', callback);

    })
    .on('error', console.error);
}



async.parallel([
  function(callback) {
    callHttp(2, callback);
  },
  function(callback) {
    callHttp(3, callback);
  },
  function(callback) {
    callHttp(4, callback);
  }], function(Err) {
  console.log(dataItems);
});
```

any idea what I could be doing wrong? I have searched everywhere and found no answers as yet

Answer (score 1):

`process.argv[5]` does not exists.

as `process.argv[5]` supposed to be fourth argument.
and you have provided only 3 process arguments.
and you are making `http` request to `undefined` url.
and so your connection refused.